# Getting the MethodInfo of static method of a static class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to get the MethodInfo of a static method in a static class. When running the following line, I only get the basic 4 methods, ToString, Equals, GetHashCode and GetType:

```
MethodInfo[] methodInfos = typeof(Program).GetMethods();
```

How can I get the other methods that are implemented in this class?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var methods = typeof(Program).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

Comment: In that case I get 0 methods back... Does it matter if I run this from the same class or from the main method?

Comment: Updated... to get all methods, both static and instance, public and nonpublic

Answer (score 6):

Try this way:

```
MethodInfo[] methodInfos = typeof(Program).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
```

Answer (score 5):

Also if you know your static method and have access to it at a compile time, you could use `Expression` class to get `MethodInfo` without directly using reflection (which may cause additional runtime errors):

```
public static void Main()
{
    MethodInfo staticMethodInfo = GetMethodInfo( () => SampleStaticMethod(0, null) );

    Console.WriteLine(staticMethodInfo.ToString());
}

//Method that is used to get MethodInfo from an expression with a static method call
public static MethodInfo GetMethodInfo(Expression<Action> expression)
{
    var member = expression.Body as MethodCallExpression;

    if (member != null)
        return member.Method;

    throw new ArgumentException("Expression is not a method", "expression");
}

public static string SampleStaticMethod(int a, string b)
{
    return a.ToString() + b.ToLower();
}
```

Here actual parameters passed to a `SampleStaticMethod` does not matter as only body of `SampleStaticMethod` is used, so you could pass `null` and default values to it.