# Expression with "where" method invoking

Tags: c#, entity-framework, system.reflection

I'm trying to achieve this kind of expression: "A => A.B.Where(extExp).Count() > 0" and I've got problem with how to make expression for Where(...) which is as I assume extension method for ICollection<>. Could someone help?

```
Expression<Func<N, bool>> conditions = c => c.T_ID == 1 || c.T_ID == 2;
ParameterExpression mpe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "A");
Expression prop = Expression.Property(mpe,typeof(T).GetProperty("B"));
...
var propWhere = Expression.Call(..., prop, conditions);
```

How to invoke it properly

Answer (score 2):

What goes there is an overload that of call that takes a MethodInfo. To get the method info I think it is best to use the code from this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/21060046/122507

```
public static MethodInfo GetMethodInfo(Expression<Action> expression)
{
    var member = expression.Body as MethodCallExpression;

    if (member != null)
        return member.Method;

    throw new ArgumentException("Expression is not a method", "expression");
}
```

usage

```
var whereMethodInfo = GetMethodInfo(() => Enumerable.Where(Enumerable.Empty<T>(), i=>true));
```

BTW I suggest that you download LINQPad and use it to write queries and look at the generated expression trees and IL code.